# Generating json data for StockChart from PHP

Tags: php, highcharts

I can not get my generator working for the StockChart, is it because of the generator syntax output?

Javascript

```
$(function () {
        // Create the chart
        $('#graphr').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data : 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/zwrotkav2/api/stockchart.php',
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                shadow : true,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                }
            }]
        });

});
```

SQL Result.

```
Date | totalCOunt
0000-00-00 | 14
2013-10-13 |  3
2013-10-16 |  1
2013-10-17 |  1
2013-10-18 |  2
2013-10-25 |  4
```

My Php generator

```
require_once("../db_config.php");

  try { 
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT  DATE(date) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT number) totalCOunt FROM numbers GROUP   BY  DATE(date)");
    $sth->execute();

    /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
    // print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

     } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 

try{
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        $date =strtotime($row['Date'])*1000;
        echo "[".$date.",". $row['totalCOunt']."],<br>"; 
        }
}
catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());}
```

Generator output
(example acceptable json http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=? )

```
[1384038000000,2],
[1384124400000,1],
[1384210800000,1],
[1384556400000,1],
[1384729200000,4],
[1385247600000,2],
[1385334000000,2],
[1385420400000,2],
[1385506800000,3],
[1385593200000,1],
```

---

Edit 2.

Using Json_Encode - generator output

```
[[0,"14"],[1381788000000,"3"],[1381874400000,"1"],[1381960800000,"1"],[1382047200000,"2"],[1382652000000,"4"],[1383001200000,"1"],[1383174000000,"1"],[1383433200000,"1"],[1383606000000,"1"],[1384038000000,"2"],[1384124400000,"1"],[1384210800000,"1"],
```

php loop

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
            $date =strtotime($row['Date'])*1000;
            $return[] = array($date,$row['totalCOunt']); 
}
```

Comment: never try and create json manually, use `json_encode()` instead

Comment: @Steve check my question update

Comment: The json adds [] tags on beginning and end and the $row gets " "

Comment: the aditional opening and closing brackets `[]` are required for valid json. If totalcount must be an integer rather than a string (quotes `"` indicate a string) then cast using `(int)` eg:  `$return[] = array($date, (int)$row['totalCOunt']);`

Comment: @Steve http://oi61.tinypic.com/m80aj6.jpg with data [[1381788000000,3],[1381874400000,1],[1381960800000,1],[1382047200000,2],[1382652000000,4]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit looks better. Now the problem you have with that line:

```
data : 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/zwrotkav2/api/stockchart.php',
```

That would do nothing. To load data you should use AJAX. [Here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#3) you can find tutorial for this.

Comment: I figured it out. Are you familiar with the highcharts? I would need some help

Comment: can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484278/dynamically-generated-stockchart [pl] byłbym wdzięczny. generowanie wykresu na podstawie zaznaczonych pol checkbox w formularzu

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with PHP. Probably you need to read about POST and GET in PHP. About 1-day problem, I guess it's connected to the UTC+2, I advice to attach a couple of timestamps used for a chart to get wrong result. [pl] Powodzenia ;)

Comment: Well do you have any foreach(or update my code) javascript that could help me completing this? I think I could adjust the php thing. [pl] a dasz radę zrobić coś w js i odpowiedzieć w tamtym temacie? Np. formularz submit leci post a w sukcesie narysuje wykres, i tak jak wspominalem if checkbox val=1 checked dorzuć serię itd. Dasz radę? Myślę ,że poradze sobię z php mając js i zaakceptuje odp

Comment: Sample data output http://pastebin.com/exgiqGH3 [pl]te polskie znaki się nie gryzą chyba bo wyświetla normalnie

Comment: A pomozesz z http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494488/passing-variable-from-a-function-into-submit-function