# Dynamically generated StockChart - Form -> Checkboxes = generate my chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

This is a example of working multi-line stock chart. Well only one small problem is - the date is moved by -1 day somehow comparing to the mysql result ( but that is not the point now ).

I wanted to create a dynamic stock generator supplied by a form. The form has some checkboxes that allows us to pick what series we want to be generated.

**#Questions & Problems**
**#1 PHP side :** Ok lets say we picked from checkbox 1 and 3. What we need to do is to post them to the generator file right? Inside the generator file there would be something like

```
if($_POST['gen_fields'] == 1){ $return['name'] = 'Zwroty';


                foreach ($result as $row) {
                $date =strtotime($row['Date'])*1000;
                $return['data'][] = array($date, (int)$row['totalCOunt']);
                // $return[] = 
                }
}
```

Well I tried that but seems to not been working somehow. Lets move on to the JS question.

**#2 JS side :** Javascript wise its also somehow hard to achieve it has to be something like a if statement : if checked checkbox 1 add to series. If no series selected error or add all 3.

**Second option** I saw some dynamic foreach series scripts on the internet but it seems that they wasn't working with my generator because I had no if $_Get's

```
<form id="form_gen" method="post" class="bootstrap-frm" style="max-width: 100% !important;">
<label>
        <span>Parameters</span> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="gen_fields" value="1"> Zwroty
        <input type="checkbox" name="gen_fields" value="2"> Doręczenia
        <input type="checkbox" name="gen_fields" value="3"> W doręczeniu
    </label>    
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="button" value="Generate" class="add-button" onclick="form_gen()">
    </label>    
</form>
```

**JS section**

```
    function form_gen() {
        $('#form_gen').form('submit', {
            url: 'api/stockchart.php',
            onSubmit: function() {

            },
            beforeSend: function() {

            },
            success: function(result) {
                $.getJSON('api/stockchart.php', function(json) {
                    // Create the chart
                    $('#as').highcharts('StockChart', {

                        rangeSelector: {
                            selected: 1
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: 'Wpisów dziennie'
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Ilość'
                            },

                            plotLines: [{}]
                        },

                        series: [{
                            name: 'Zwroty',
                            color: '#4572A7',
                            type: 'column',
                            // yAxis: 1,
                            data: json[1].data
                        }, {
                            name: 'Doręczenia',
                            color: '#45CCA7',
                            type: 'column',
                            // yAxis: 1,
                            data: json[2].data
                        }, {
                            name: 'W doręczeniu',
                            color: '#89A54E',
                            type: 'spline',
                            data: json[0].data 
                        }]
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The PHP generator

```
      try { 
        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT  DATE(date) Date, COUNT(number) totalCOunt FROM numbers GROUP BY  DATE(date)");
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();

        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT  DATE(rdate) Date, COUNT(number) totalCOunt FROM numbers Where `return` = 2 AND rdate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' GROUP BY  DATE(rdate)");
        $sth->execute();
        $returna = $sth->fetchAll();

        $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT  DATE(rdate) Date, COUNT(number) totalCOunt FROM numbers Where `return` = 1 AND rdate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' GROUP BY  DATE(rdate)");
        $sth->execute();
        $returnb = $sth->fetchAll();

        /* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
        // print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");


         } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 

    try{
            $return['name'] = 'Zwroty';


            foreach ($result as $row) {
            $date =strtotime($row['Date'])*1000;
            $return['data'][] = array($date, (int)$row['totalCOunt']);
            // $return[] = 
            }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 



    try{
            $return1['name'] = 'W doręczeniu';
            foreach ($returna as $row1) {
            $date1 =strtotime($row1['Date'])*1000;
            $return1['data'][] = array($date1, (int)$row1['totalCOunt']);
            // $return[] = 
            }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 

    try{
            $return2['name'] = 'Doręczony';
            foreach ($returnb as $row2) {
            $date2 =strtotime($row2['Date'])*1000;
            $return2['data'][] = array($date2, (int)$row2['totalCOunt']);
            // $return[] = 
            }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 

    $result = array();
array_push($result,$return);
array_push($result,$return1);
array_push($result,$return2);
echo json_encode($result,true);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? Have you tried to use `series: json` instead? And colors you can set in [colors array](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors).

Comment: This example works perfectly I want to adapt it to the form.[pl] jak nacisniesz formularz to ma pobrac dane z pola gen_fields i jak jest wartosc 1 to dodaje serie jak 2 tez itd. Wiesz dynamicznie, z php sobie poradze

Comment: If you want, you can contact directly with our support team on our email - we can then speak polish :)

Comment: Done. Lets try it later I can answer here the correct solution