# Passing variable from a function into submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery

$('.report_filter input') get value of selected radio box sending the variable to function report_operation, from there on I hide some fields based on the selection

$(".js-ajax-php-json") ajax form submission, I want to get inside the .submit the var value. There I could do some if empty field return false to stop the form from submitting. For instance if field name="number" is empty and the var value is 1 return false; This can't be made by a simple form validator, its a quite dynamic form.

I just have no idea how to do that

```
$('.report_filter input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
                             var val = $(this).val();
                             raport_operation(val);
                        });

                            $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
                            var data = {
                              "action": "test1"
                            };
                            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
                            alert(raport_operation());
                                // if ($("#number").val() == "" and val == 1) {
                                // alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
                                // return false;
                                // }
                            $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              dataType: "json",
                              url: "api/response.php",
                              data: data,
                              success: function(data) {
                              draw_graph(data);
                                $(".the-return").html(data);
                                //alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
                              }
                            });
                            return false;
                      });


                        function raport_operation(query){
                            //alert(val);
                            if(query==1){ //number
                                //alert(1);
                                $('#segment_optional').hide('slow');
                                $('#segment_number').show('slow');
                                $('#segment_optional').show('slow');
                                $('#segment_customer').hide('slow');
                                $('#segment_listType').hide('slow');
                                $('#segment_customer').val('');
                                $('#reportdate_to').val('');
                                $('#reportdate_from').val('');
                                // $('#segment_general').hide();
                            }
    }
```

Comment: How your data in ajax looks like ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I figured it out myself :) it was passed in form I forgot about it